# Limit of The Dirac Comb

Tags: limits, dirac-delta

The [Dirac comb function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) with period T is:
$$
f(t,T):=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}\delta(t-kT)
$$

What is the limit of:
$$
\lim_{T\to0} f(t,T)
$$
?

Comment: The limit of f(t,T) is the constant function: f(t) = 1.

Comment: @M.Wind. No, it isn't. For that to happen, you need to multiply it with $T$. That is,
$$\lim_{T \to 0} T \sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}\delta(t-kT) = 1$$
for all $t$.

Instead we have
$$\lim_{T\to0} f(t,T) = \infty.$$

Comment: Apologies. I tacitly assumed that the function is properly normalized. There is not much point in considering the properties of a function which obviously diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively it is clear that a very dense set of Dirac functions with constant amplitude, and properly normalized, behaves as the unit constant function. Therefore we expect that the limit of the (normalized) Dirac comb function for $T$ to zero is $f(t) = 1$.

Let us see if we can derive this result a bit more rigorously. Consider a Dirac comb function in the time domain with period $T$. Performing the Fourier transformation yields a Dirac comb function in the frequency domain with period $1/T$. We now take the limit of $T$ to zero. Only the Dirac function at $f=0$ remains, since all the others shift to plus or minus infinity, where they can be assumed to contribute no longer. Now perform the Fourier transformation back to the time regime on the remaining Dirac function. You get the constant function: $f(t) = 1$.